# validate phone number length between 5-15

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to validated phone number in react native. Phone number minimum length should be 5 and maximum 15. I created a function for that but it's showing error when number is above 5. Can someone tell me how to validate it properly?

```
if (!/(^\d{15}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(phoneNumber)) {
      return strings.PLEASE_ENTER_PHONE_NUMBER_VALID;
    }
```

Comment: Add `{5,15}$/` for min and max length

Comment: There is always `phoneNumber.length`. Although, I'm not clear what format the phone number should be in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12345-1234 and 1234512345112345  both work as expected

https://regex101.com/r/bDFFE9/1

Do you mean 5 to 15 digits are ok? Then you need

```
/(^\d{5,15}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/bDFFE9/3/

Like

```js
const testPhone = phoneNumber => {
  if (!/(^\d{5,15}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(phoneNumber)) {
    return "PLEASE_ENTER_PHONE_NUMBER_VALID";
  }
  return "ok"
};

// ok:
console.log(testPhone("12345"))
console.log(testPhone("12345-1234"))
console.log(testPhone("1234512345"))
console.log(testPhone("123451234512345"))

//nok

console.log(testPhone("1234"))
console.log(testPhone("12345--1234"))
console.log(testPhone("12345123451234512345"))
```

Comment: `(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)` can you tell what's that for?

Comment: It is your original code. 5 digits, a dash and 4 digits

Comment: I know, but I don't know what's that? my sir gave me that verification code but he didn't explain it

Comment: It means 5 {5} digits \d a dash and 4 {4} digits \d from start ^ till end $ of string